# Find limit of Fibonacci numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be the sequence of Fibonacci numbers, i.e. $a_1 = a_2 = 1, a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}, n \ge 3$. Find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}.$$

Comment: The Fibonacci sequence is unbounded. Are you sure this is the question? Specifically, are you *positive* the question is not asking for the limit of the ratio between successive terms, i.e. $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$?

Comment: Thanks. I've already edited the question.

Comment: That makes more sense.

Comment: I'm guessing this approaches the golden ratio.

Answer (score 0):

All terms are strictly positive, hence a strictly increasing sequence of integers. Conclude.

UPDATE after problem statement modified.

Using the well known formula $F_n=\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(\phi^n-\frac1{(-\phi)^n}\right)$ obtained by solving the linear recurrence, you easily get that the limit is $\phi$.

Comment: The question has been edited.

Comment: Thanks. I've already edited the question.

Comment: (You should mention that the term $\frac1{(-\phi)^n}$ goes to zero because $\frac1\phi\approx0.618<1$. Remember that if $\lvert z\rvert<1$, $z^n$ goes to $0$.)

Comment: That's what I meant by "easily".

Comment: Oh, thank You. For me, this formula became well known 30 minutes ago. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hint : for every $n \in \mathbb N$  ,  $F_n =\frac {(1+\sqrt 5)^n- (1-\sqrt 5)^n}{2^n\sqrt 5} $